# SQL Database design - date / time as primary key

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I need some help with the design of a manufacturing database.

I have several data streams that I need to join together that all relate to a manufacturing line.  Each data source is collected separately, and can only be joined after the production run is complete.

The question is how to relate the streams, especially since I'm doing this post-population of the data into .csv files.  I can import each data source into Access as a separate table, but my only point of linkage between the tables is the time stamps, which we can't assume to be all overlapping.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the schema of the data source(s) and some mock data and how you are currently using these datasources ? At first thought it appears that all these tables have data for ONE Production run ... so a Prod_Id column can be added to each table(in Access) that can be used to join these tables

Answer (score 0):

Enrich your data with a generated "production run id", so you know which run your data relates to. The enrichment can be done during the import process or just after the import process. You can have a separate production run table as well to retain some information regarding the runs themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding a product run ID will help, unless I convert the line date/time to some sort of string ID, because I don't have a map of product run ID to the date/time, and the date/time is the only common thread between all these sources of data.

Comment: The data sources are either quality checks, or process data, environmental data, etc.  Each of these data streams can be updated from every second to every hour or so.  Date/time is the only way I know how to relate them.

Comment: Can you run multiple product runs at the same time in your machinery?

Comment: No - it's only one line and one product at a time.  What I'm trying to distinguish is the properties of each unit as they come of the line, as the process varies over time.

Comment: If you only have 1 product run at a time, then after completing the product run you can download the data and enrich it by assigning an artificial product run id to the records.